# Saving Calendar Selected Date to SQL database ASP.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio, calendar

I am developing a little project for a local school and I am pretty much what you can call a newbie in programming.
I am trying to retrieve a selected date by the user in the calendar to save to a separate database. I have an Entity Framework model (.edmx) to link the table in Visual Studio that I need.
This is what I got so far:

ASP.net:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<div class="main_banner">
    </div>
    <div class="main_container">
        <div class="main_heading">
            <h1 class="main_title">Projector Inspection</h1>
            <p><a href="AddProjector.aspx">Add</a> new Projector</p>
        </div>
        <div class="info_container">
            <div>
                <asp:Label ID="RoomNolbl" runat="server" Text="Room No:"></asp:Label>
             </div>
            <div>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="Roomsdbo" DataTextField="Room_No" DataValueField="Room_No" AutoPostBack="True">
                    <asp:ListItem>---Select Room---</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList> 
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Roomsdbo" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:iPadLoanConnectionString2 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Room_No] FROM [tblRooms]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
             </div>

             <div>
                <asp:Label ID="Datelbl" runat="server" Text="Date Checked:"></asp:Label>
             </div>
            <div>
                <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="White" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="9pt" ForeColor="Black" Height="190px" NextPrevFormat="FullMonth" Width="350px" OnSelectionChanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged1" DayNameFormat="Shortest">
                    <DayHeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="8pt" />
                    <NextPrevStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#333333" VerticalAlign="Bottom" />
                    <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#999999" />
                    <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#333399" ForeColor="White" />
                    <TitleStyle BackColor="White" BorderColor="#ae1022" BorderWidth="4px" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="12pt" ForeColor="#ae1022" />
                    <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                </asp:Calendar>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Calendartxt" runat="server" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
             </div>

            <div class ="info_container_task">
                <h3>Task carried</h3>
            <div>
                <asp:Label ID="CheckBoxFilterlbl" runat="server" Text="Filter Cleaning:"></asp:Label>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxFilter" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBoxFilter_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <asp:Label ID="CheckBoxBulblbl" runat="server" Text="Bulb Replacement:"></asp:Label>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxBulb" runat="server"  OnCheckedChanged="CheckBoxBulb_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <asp:Button ID="ButtonSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="ButtonSubmit_Click" />
            </div>
          </div>
             <div>
                <asp:Label ID="HourCountBulblbl" runat="server" Text="Bulb Hours:"></asp:Label>
             </div>
            <div>
                <asp:TextBox ID="HourBulbtxt" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
             </div>
            <div>
                <asp:Label ID="FilterHourlbl" runat="server" Text="Filter Hours:"></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <asp:TextBox ID="FilterHourtxt" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
             <div>
                <asp:Label ID="Commentslbl" runat="server" Text="Additional Comments:" ></asp:Label>
             </div>
            <div>
                <textarea id="Commentstxt" cols="20" rows="2" ></textarea>&nbsp;</div>
        </div>

    </div>
<div class="sub_container">
    <h2>Additional Information</h2>
<div class="Tbl_Projectorinfo">
    <div class="projectorGrid">
            <asp:GridView ID="projectorinfo" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="linkprojectorsdbo" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" DataKeyNames="Model_No">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Current_Hours" HeaderText="Current_Hours" SortExpression="Current_Hours" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Last_Replacement_Date" HeaderText="Last_Replacement_Date" SortExpression="Last_Replacement_Date" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Last_Cleaned" HeaderText="Last_Cleaned" SortExpression="Last_Cleaned" />
                </Columns>
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#ae1022" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#ae1022" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="linkprojectorsdbo" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:iPadLoanConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Model_No], [Current_Hours], [Last_Replacement_Date], [Last_Cleaned] FROM [tblProjectors] WHERE ([Room_No] = @Room_No)">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="Room_No" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="tblModels" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Manufacturer" HeaderText="Manufacturer" SortExpression="Manufacturer" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Model_Name" HeaderText="Model" SortExpression="Model_Name" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Min_Hours" HeaderText="MinHours" SortExpression="Min_Hours" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Max_Hours" HeaderText="MaxHours" SortExpression="Max_Hours" />
                </Columns>
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#ae1022" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#ae1022" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="tblModels" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:iPadLoanConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Manufacturer], [Model_Name], [Min_Hours], [Max_Hours] FROM [ProjectorsRoom2017] WHERE ([Room_No] = @Room_No)">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="Room_No" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
        </div>
    </div>
```

.cs File:

```
 protected void ButtonSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tblProjector entry = new tblProjector();
        entry.Last_Cleaned = Convert.ToDateTime(Calendartxt.Text);
        iPadLoanEntities db = new iPadLoanEntities();
        db.tblProjectors.Add(entry);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }




    protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Calendartxt.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
    }
}
```

I am constantly getting an error saying validation for one or more than one entities failed. Also the error points to the line of code:

```
db.SaveChanges();
```

I know that with that code I am trying to get the information of the TextBox that is linked to the calendar to be saved to the database but to be honest saving it directly from the calendar would be great if it is possible.

If anyone could give me a hand on how to be able to achieve this I would be grateful. Thanks

Comment: `entry.Last_Cleaned = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();` would get it direct from the calendar, wouldn't it? I don't know if your DB will accept it in that string format though, you might have to convert it to something more machine-readable like YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss format or something. Or just do `entry.Last_Cleaned = Calendar1.SelectedDate`  if both Last_Cleaned and SelectedDate are of type DateTime, then there's no messing about with string represenations of the date.

Comment: @ADyson Last_Cleaned is DateTime as I have set it in SQL Management Studio. When you select a date in the calendar is the format also DateTime? The date rendered in the text box linked is showing as MM-D-YYYY

Comment: The string format is irrelevant, it's for display only. DateTimes are stored as numbers internally. You shouldn't use or rely on the string format for anything at all except the sole purpose of showing it to a human being. For moving data around, use a DateTime object. And yes, `Calendar.SelectedDate` is a DateTime - you can check this in the docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.selecteddate(v=vs.110).aspx. Therefore `entry.Last_Cleaned = Calendar1.SelectedDate` should just work with no worry about the format. Try it and see.

Comment: Oh ok, that made things a lot clearer! I will try it as soon as I get to the laptop and let you know if it worked. Thanks @ADyson

Comment: @ADyson I have tried as you said and still coming up with the same

Comment: Hm. What's the exact error? Are there some other fields in the table that you're supposed to fill in as well? It might be useful to show the schema for your tblProjectors table.

Comment: Oh that might be my mistake then, there are a few more columns to which I have not created the data binding events yet. I thought I could do one by one and test them as long as I allowed null values. That is the error( "Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.") @ADyson

Comment: hm, if the other fields all allow NULL then you shouldn't have to specify values when creating the EF object.. With that error, if you set a breakpoint you should be able to examine the exception and inspect the EntityValidationErrors property (or you can write some code to catch and log it). Then it'll be easier to see exactly what's going wrong.

Comment: @ADyson k, I will have a look at that and update if I find a solution. Thanks for all the help